# "To Do" App, Auto start

Tags: autostart

I have just done a clean install of 22.04 and I am setting up my auto start programs. I am trying to add the To Do app,but can't remember the proper name for it in terminal. Can anyone help please. Cheers Dave

I have tried:

todo
to-do
to do

But no luck?

Answer (score 1):

Yay!

Figured it out!

gnome-todo

is the full name for it!